# How to write specific time interval of GstSamples (RTP over UDP H264 packets)?

Tags: c++, udp, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

#### The Setup

I am sending H.264 encoded packets over RTP UDP via the following Gstreamer CLI pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! timeoverlay ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

Note that `timeoverlay` element will come in handy later on!

At the receiver side and for depiction only (this is not launched from the CLI), I use the following pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,clock-rate=90000,payload=96 ! queue ! appsink`

Note that `udpsrc`'s property of `do-timestamp` is set to true by default. So it is the element that is actually timestamping the buffers here.

Using Gstreamer's `appsink` element I extract `GstSample*` and unix-timestamp them manually and keep them in a queue. The timestamp I did has nothing to do with presentation timestamp of sample's buffer as in`GST_BUFFER_PTS(buffer)` it's rather implemented as follows:

```
struct MyGstSample {
  GstSample* sample_;
  long unix_time_ns_;
}
```

Upon requesting a specific unix time interval, I should feed the corresponding
samples `GstSample*` from the queue to a separate pipeline via Gstreamer's `appsrc` via the following pipeline (for depiction only) and record the interval in a `.mp4` file:

`gst-launch-1.0 appsrc ! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! queue ! filesink`

#### The Problem

I can't seem to write the required interval precisely, you can tell by the time shown in the recorded video, Thanks to `timeoverlay`. For example, if the user requests (from running time 5s to running time 15s for simplicity) I only get from 10s to 15s. I guess this has something to do with a key frame issue or something.

Is there a way where I can keep the frames encoded and yet still ensure precise on-demand video recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem actually relates to the key frames as the recording pipeline will only start writing the video from the first key frame it finds, all the delta frames are discarded. And the reason why I miss a lot of seconds in the requested interval is because of the configuration of the sender pipeline sending one key frame every 300 frame, This property relates to the `x264enc`.

Adjusting the sender pipeline to send key frame every 30 frames:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! timeoverlay ! videoconvert ! x264enc key-int-max=30 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

Next up we need to figure out which buffers `GstBuffer *` correspond to key frames. This can be done by checking if buffer has the `GST_BUFFER_FLAG_DELTA_UNIT` set by `GST_BUFFER_FLAG_IS_SET(buf, GST_BUFFER_FLAG_DELTA_UNIT)`

At the receiver's side and upon probing the buffers coming out of the `udpsrc`, you will find that `GST_BUFFER_FLAG_DELTA_UNIT` is always set to false because the data is `application/x-rtp`. Here you will need to use `rtph264depay` and check the buffers coming out of it. You will start seeing some key frames and delta frames. With that said, the receiver's side should be as follows:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,clock-rate=90000,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! queue ! appsink`

And finally for the recording pipeline to work, you will need to obtain the `GstCaps*` of the `rtph264depay`'s src pad from the receiver's side and use it as the caps for the `appsrc` in the recording pipeline since it contains important codec-specific data. otherwise parser `h264parse` will not be able to function properly. Here's the pipeline (for depiction only, you still need to add the caps to the appsrc though)

`gst-launch-1.0 appsrc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! queue ! filesink`

With that said, whenever we receive a requested interval, will actually search for the nearest key frame in the queue and start feeding the corresponding samples to recording pipeline.

Comment: Regarding the codec-specific data part of the h264, it's because the stream-format of the h264 was avc. If you switch to byte-stream, then you won't need that codec-specific data anymore.